# How to increase spacing between two lines?

Tags: line-breaking

I am new to LaTeX. I was writing a document in LaTeX. I want to increase the spacing between the vertical lines, I can use `\vspace{2mm}` but that is not possible to write at end of every line.

So can you please tell me a code for this.

Comment: I presume you mean `increase the vertical spacing between the lines` instead of `increase the spacing between the vertical lines`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's also the `setspace` package (place in preamble):

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
%\doublespacing
```

There's `\openup` macro (to use in text).

```
\openup .5em
\lipsum[3]}
```

You could also

```
\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip
\lipsum[3]}
```

Answer (score 9):

The 2nd argument to `\fontsize` provides the default baselineskip (the first argument is the font size)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\fontsize{10pt}{14pt}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]

\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]